# Interface builder: lock selection

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Is it possible to select an item in the outline view (under "Object") and lock the selection so I wont be able to select any other item in the canvas?

Basically, I have lots of objects all over the canvas and would like to move the items around but every time I click there something else gets selected.

Answer (score 1):

No way that I know of. Annoying. The only workaround I have found is to select elements through the sidebar, not by clicking on them directly. Also moving things with the arrow keys when dragging would result in deselection or incorrect layer reordering (which happens with Views).

Answer (score -1):

`shift` + `right click` pulls up a menu which allows you to choose what you want to select